# Simple Code to Copy Same Name Properties?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I have an **old** question sustained in my mind for a long time. When I was writing code in Spring, there are lots dirty and useless code for DTO, domain objects. For language level, I am hopeless in Java and see some light in Kotlin. Here is my question:

**Style 1**  It is common for us to write following code (Java, C++, C#, ...)

```
    // annot: AdminPresentation 
    val override = FieldMetadataOverride()
    override.broadleafEnumeration = annot.broadleafEnumeration
    override.hideEnumerationIfEmpty = annot.hideEnumerationIfEmpty
    override.fieldComponentRenderer = annot.fieldComponentRenderer
```

**Sytle 2** Previous code can be simplified by using `T.apply()` in Kotlin

```
    override.apply {
        broadleafEnumeration = annot.broadleafEnumeration
        hideEnumerationIfEmpty = annot.hideEnumerationIfEmpty
        fieldComponentRenderer = annot.fieldComponentRenderer
    }
```

**Sytle 3**  ***Can such code be even simplified to something like this?***

```
    override.copySameNamePropertiesFrom (annot) { // provide property list here
        broadleafEnumeration
        hideEnumerationIfEmpty
        fieldComponentRenderer
    }
```

***First Priority Requirments***

1. Provide `property name` list only one time
2. The `property name` is provided as normal code, so as to we can get IDE auto complete feature.

***Second Priority Requirements***

3. It's prefer to avoid run-time cost for Style 3. (For example, 'reflection' may be a possible implementation, but it do introduce cost.)
4. It's prefer to generated code like style1/style2 directly.

***Not care***

5. The final syntax of Style 3.

I am a novice for Kotlin language. Is it possible to use Kotlin to define somthing like 'Style 3' ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be pretty simple to write a 5 line helper to do this which even supports copying every matching property or just a selection of properties.

Although it's probably not useful if you're writing Kotlin code and heavily utilising data classes and `val` (immutable properties). Check it out:

```
fun <T : Any, R : Any> T.copyPropsFrom(fromObject: R, vararg props: KProperty<*>) {
  // only consider mutable properties
  val mutableProps = this::class.memberProperties.filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()
  // if source list is provided use that otherwise use all available properties
  val sourceProps = if (props.isEmpty()) fromObject::class.memberProperties else props.toList()
  // copy all matching
  mutableProps.forEach { targetProp ->
    sourceProps.find {
      // make sure properties have same name and compatible types 
      it.name == targetProp.name && targetProp.returnType.isSupertypeOf(it.returnType) 
    }?.let { matchingProp ->
      targetProp.setter.call(this, matchingProp.getter.call(fromObject))
    }
  }
}
```

This approach uses reflection, but it uses Kotlin reflection which is very lightweight. I haven't timed anything, but it should run almost at same speed as copying properties by hand.

Now given 2 classes:

```
data class DataOne(val propA: String, val propB: String)
data class DataTwo(var propA: String = "", var propB: String = "")
```

You can do the following:

```
  var data2 = DataTwo()
  var data1 = DataOne("a", "b")
  println("Before")
  println(data1)
  println(data2)
  // this copies all matching properties
  data2.copyPropsFrom(data1)
  println("After")
  println(data1)
  println(data2)
  data2 = DataTwo()
  data1 = DataOne("a", "b")
  println("Before")
  println(data1)
  println(data2)
  // this copies only matching properties from the provided list 
  // with complete refactoring and completion support
  data2.copyPropsFrom(data1, DataOne::propA)
  println("After")
  println(data1)
  println(data2)
```

Output will be:

```
Before
DataOne(propA=a, propB=b)
DataTwo(propA=, propB=)
After
DataOne(propA=a, propB=b)
DataTwo(propA=a, propB=b)
Before
DataOne(propA=a, propB=b)
DataTwo(propA=, propB=)
After
DataOne(propA=a, propB=b)
DataTwo(propA=a, propB=)
```

Comment: Nice! I am figuring how to simplify `DataOne::propA`. I smelled some JavaScript, C++/Java 8 smell here. Really nice.

Comment: I removed ugly `DataOne::` with 

    `fun <T : Any, R : Any> T.copyPropsFrom(fromObject: R, getProps : T.() -> Array<KProperty<*>>) `  so I can the function as  

    `data2.copyPropsFrom(data2){
        arrayOf(::propA, ::propB)
    }`  but the `arrayOf()` is still very ugly.

Comment: A. I cannot remote arrayOf(). 
B. It is implemented by reflection, the complexity should by O(n).
C. The answer is acceptable. In heart of this simplification is `::propA` syntax provided by Kotlin.