# Implement domain <-> dto mapper functionality in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

We use Kotlin in a SpringBoot environment. The API's use DTO's (data classes) in there interfaces, while the business logic uses DomainObjects. For Kotlin, we have not found a suitable model mapper that does handle differences in nullability, (abstract) subclass differences and also does that using strong types lambda expressions for properties (instead of property names in strings).

Does anyone now a suitable library? Or could we ask for Kotlin to provide this functionality?

Comment: Do you mean something like TT files in C#, that generates your domain data classes from DTO classes. Passing all arguments to it or do some magic stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Always better to write this sort of stuff explicitly in my opinion.

You can write a 5 line helper that will copy same named properties for example to reduce verbosity just a little bit if the size of objects is very large. I gave an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49043283/2788).